# Ruby on Rails, Running Guard, dies right away with "Killed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, spork, guard

I've installed guard and spork according to Ryan Bates' RailsCast (under Linux Mint 12), and the guard process is showing "Killed" as soon as it starts up.  Running "bundle exec guard --verbose" gives:

bundle exec guard --verbose
DEBUG (12:17:27): Command execution: which notify-send

Guard uses NotifySend to send notifications.

Guard is now watching at 'path_to_project'

DEBUG (12:17:27): Hook :start_begin executed for Guard::Spork

DEBUG (12:17:27): Command execution: ps aux | awk '/spork/&&!/awk/{print $2;}'

DEBUG (12:17:27): Killing Spork servers with PID: 8884

Killed

I've tried tweaking the values in the guard gem documentation's "Advanced Linux system configuration" (max_queued_events and max_user_instances, max_users_watches).  No joy there at much higher than default values for all.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance if so.  Google-fu has revealed nothing useful so far for this particular issue.

Comment: Sounds like this could be an issue with Spork.  Have you tried running guard without Spork? Likewise, have you tried running Spork without guard to see what happens.  Can you post your Guardfile?

Comment: can you post Guardfile, and gemfile section with any test related gems... also which version of Rails, which ruby?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen now and then. What you need to do is find the running spork process and kill it. For instance:

```
ps aux | grep spork
```

Note the pid of any active spork processes (first column). If it happened to be 123, then type:

```
kill 123
```

And then start up guard again.